# Can I fetch data from database, inside the post method form?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have duplicate databases and I want to fetch data from the secondary database, inside my Register form which has `POST` method.

I tried what I can do still stuck on it few days.

This is my `register.blade` where I want to fetch data :

```php
{{ csrf_field() }}
@if($getTypes->count())
@foreach($getTypes as $getType)
  <option value="{{$getType->nameMn}}">
    {{$getType->nameMn}}
  </option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Here is the controller :

```php
public function getTypes(){
  $db = DB::connection('mysql2');
  $getTypes = $db->table('merchant_types')->get();

  return view('auth/register', ['getTypes'=>$getTypes]);
}
```

```php
Route::post('register', 'MerchantController@getTypes');
```

And here goes the Route, I've tried post & get everything.

On my view blade this error is showing :

> Undefined variable: getTypes"

Comment: what gives dd($getTypes); in your Controller? It seems it's not defined.

Comment: On this blade it shows nothing, so I tried creating new blade just changed the Route 'register' and in that way it displays my data.

Answer (score 0):

You should use compact('getTypes') instead of ['getTypes'=>$getTypes], change Route::post to Route::get and then open it in browser, dd($getTypes) in view to see which type of object. I can not see what wrong.

Comment: you did something, I try to create new one and it's working fine